# What is a extensive ASP.NET MVC sample app that uses the entity framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can anyone suggest an ASP.NET MVC sample application that uses the ADO.NET Entity Framework against a many relation sql server database?

Most of the sample apps I've seen work against a really simple database with just 2 or 3 tables. I'd like to see the code behind an app that shows more than just the CRUD code to just one table

Thanks for any suggestions!

Rob

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider [an example that has been built](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/01/29/asp-net-mvc-example-application-over-northwind-with-the-entity-framework.aspx) using ASP.NET MVC and the Entity Framework using the Northwind database, which is a pretty good representation of a typical business-type database.

Also, if you're not familiar with the web site already, [ASP.NET](http://asp.net) has some great resources for [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/).

Answer (score 0):

Rob Conery StoreFont is a good point to start looking, but it's done with L2S (not much diference anyway)

Source Code here: http://www.codeplex.com/mvcsamples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=18861